# jquery Displaying an image based on two dropdown list combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple website than only shows some images based on the combination of two drop down lists, so far my code is like this (html):

```
  <p> Origen <select id="origen" > 
  <option>Todos los orígenes</option> 
  <option  >Acapulco</option>
  <option  >Cancún</option>
  <option> Chicago</option>
  <option>Ciudad de México</option>
  <option>Ixtapa/Zihuatanejo</option>
  <option>La Paz</option>
  <option>León</option>
  <option>Los Ángeles</option>
  <option>Mazatlán</option>
  <option>Monterrey</option>
  <option>Morelia</option>
  <option>Ontario</option>
  <option>Reno</option>
  <option>San José, California</option>
  <option>San José, Costa Rica</option>
  <option>Seattle</option>
  <option>Tijuana</option>
  <option>Veracruz</option>
</select>

<p> Destino <select id="destino" > 
  <option>Todos los orígenes</option> 
  <option  >Acapulco</option>
  <option  >Cancú</option>
  <option> Chicago</option>
  <option>Ciudad de México</option>
  <option>Ixtapa/Zihuatanejo</option>
  <option>La Paz</option>
  <option>León</option>
  <option>Los Ángeles</option>
  <option>Mazatlán</option>
  <option>Monterrey</option>
  <option>Morelia</option>
  <option>Ontario</option>
  <option>Reno</option>
  <option>San José, California</option>
  <option>San José, Costa Rica</option>
  <option>Seattle</option>
  <option>Tijuana</option>
  <option>Veracruz</option>
</select>
```

I've tried jquery and scripts, but I'm noob with that, all the examples I've found work only for one dropdown list.

Comment: Please post the HTML and the JS which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#origin, #destino').change(function() {

   var originVal = $('#origin option:selected').val();
   var destinoVal = $('#destino option:selected').val();

   if (originVal == 'somevalue' && detinoVal == 'somevalue') 
   {
      $('img').attr('src','image path');
   }

   //todo: other if statement

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specified how/where to display an image, but to get the event of the two selected dropdowns you could use JQuery:

```
$('#origin, #destino').change(function(){
     if($("#origin").val() && $("#destino").val()){
          $('#yourImage').attr('src','imgPath');
     }
});
```